# timed event in FullCalendar 5.1, time label format

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar, frontend

I would like to change date format display in FullCalendar for timed events. For now I have something like that:

[image]

I want to change "22" to "22:00" but I am unable to find any property responsible for modifying this. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The following is from the Full Calendar site on how to set the `eventTimeFormat` property when setting up the calendar. I believe the first option meets your needs.

```
// TimeGrid views. '7:00'
{
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: '2-digit',
  meridiem: false
}

// DayGrid views. '7p'
{
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: '2-digit',
  omitZeroMinute: true,
  meridiem: 'narrow'
}

// List views. '7pm'
{
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: '2-digit',
  meridiem: 'short'
}
```

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventTimeFormat

Comment: You can also set hour12 within those to false if you would like to use 24 hour time.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I have added to calendar options:

```
eventTimeFormat: {
      hour: '2-digit',
      minute: '2-digit'
    },
```